# When are type coercions done in C when assigning the result of an arithmetic expression?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Suppose I have the following code:

Suppose I have `type x = EXPR;`, where `type` is some type and `EXPR` is some arithmetic expression.

In what circumstances is the result of evaluating EXPR coerced? When does this coercion happen? In what cases does this coercion result in undefined behaviour?

NOTE: I previously asked about

```
unsigned a = 60000, b = 60000;
int c = a * b;
```

where int is `16` bits, but decided to edit it to the more general case, as this is more useful.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me...

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks, just trying to settle an argument basically

Comment: What the other side is claiming?  It's easier t refute a false argument.

Comment: Note that, in the terminology of the C standard, `a * b` does not overflow. For unsigned operands, the defined result is the mathematical result reduced modulo the applicable modulus, and the defined result is always representable in the type, so it never overflows the type.

Comment: The title asks a general question, but the body asks about a specific and unremarkable situation. Answering the title would entail listing quite a few rules from the C standard, whereas answering the body is little more than, sure, that is right. It would be good to edit one or the other to reduce this disparity.

Comment: The reduction for `unsigned int` is done modulo one more than `UINT_MAX`, not modulo `UINT_MAX`. So `(60000 * 60000) % UINT_MAX` and `31380` is wrong. The correct value is 60000•60000 modulo 65536, which is 41984. Also, `b = 6000` is apparently intended to be `b = 60000`. 41984 will not fit in a 16-bit `int`, so overflow occurs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. other side claimed that the above is undefined behaviour because of signed overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right, the title is a much more interesting question than the body. Since I've already got an answer to the body, I'll edit this to have the body match the title.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Also note that your calculations are incorrect as Eric have shown. `60000*60000` will actually not fit `int` and cause an implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right about the math being off. I didn't bother to check it, the example was given by another person. I've edited it to ask about the more general case, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I have `type x = EXPR;`, where `type` is some type and `EXPR`
>   is some arithmetic expression.
>
> In what circumstances is the result of evaluating EXPR coerced?

As long as this is a [language-lawyer] question, I feel compelled to observe that no form of the verb "coerce" appears in the language standard.  The verb used is usually "convert" and occasionally "promote", whether it occurs explicitly (by evaluating a cast expression) or otherwise.

With that said, the standard defines the behavior of the assignment operator subject to the constraint ([C2011, 6.5.16/2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p2)) that

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and the constraint  ([C2011, 6.5.16.1/1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1); summarized) that one of the following holds:

- the left and right operands have arithmetic types;
- the left and right operands have compatible structure or union types;
- the left and right operand types are pointers to compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of that pointed to by the right;
- the left operand has an object pointer type, the right is a pointer to `void`, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of that pointed to by the right;
- the left operand has pointer type, and the right is a null pointer constant; or
- the left operand has a `_Bool` type, and the right is a pointer.

**Where either of those constraints does not hold, the standard does not define any behavior for the assignment operator, so its behavior is undefined**.  Where they both do hold the standard addresses this particular question pretty directly:

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted
>   to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored
>   in the object designated by the left operand.

([C2011 6.5.16.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p2))

, where

> The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion.

([C2011 6.5.16/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p3))

So, the answer is technically that `EXPR` is converted automatically in all cases that satisfy the constraint, and all effects of the assignment (including whether any conversion is performed) are undefined otherwise.  I say "technically" because the plain wording of the standard makes no exception for the case where the types of the two operands are identical, but you might not actually want to count that.

> When
>   does this coercion happen?

In the abstract-machine sense, it must happen after the value of `EXPR` is computed, for until then there isn't anything to convert, and before the side effect of the assignment operator is applied (and that must be complete by the sequence point that occurs at the terminating semicolon).

> In what cases does this coercion result in
>   undefined behaviour?

According to the rules for conversions presented in [section 6.3 of the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3), **for those type combinations permitted by assignment, UB occurs when**

- a value of real type is converted to a real floating type where the value is out of range for the target type
- a non-finite real floating value is converted to any integer type other than `_Bool`
- a finite real floating value is converted to any integer type other than `_Bool` that cannot represent the result of truncating it to an integer (even if the target type is unsigned)
- a complex value is converted to any real type, and UB arises from conversion of its real part, taken as a value of the corresponding real type, to the destination type
- a value of real type is converted to a complex type where UB arises from the conversion of the source value to the target type's corresponding real type
- a complex value is converted to another complex type where UB arises from conversion of either the real or the imaginary part, taken as a value of the source type's corresponding real type, to the destination type's corresponding real type

**Notable cases that do not produce UB include**

- conversion of any value of integer type to a signed integer type that cannot represent the value.  That's implementation-defined (or an implementation-defined signal is raised), not undefined.  That's a significant distinction, but it still leaves this case being a portability issue.
- conversion of any value of integer type to an unsigned integer type.  All such conversions have well-defined results (but the same does not apply to conversions from other scalar types to unsigned integer types).

**Notable cases that do not satisfy the constraint for simple assignment include**

- the left operand has `const`-qualified type or otherwise is not a modifiable lvalue
- one operand has a pointer type and the other an integer type, except if the integer type is `_Bool` and it appears on the left; and
- both operands have pointer types pointing to non-`void`, incompatible types.

Note also that the rules for evaluating some operations specify undefinedness rules that are not wholly analogous with the rules for conversions or with each other.  For the most part, these cases revolve around operations with operands and / or results of signed integer types.

Comment: The term "coerce" is a language-agnostic term used to describe type conversions that are applied automatically in situations where an operation that requires a value of one type is performed upon an operand of another, as distinct from type conversions that occur for other reasons such as casts.

Comment: @supercat, I know what the term means, and if I didn't then I certainly know how to look it up.  But in a language-lawyer question, it serves everyone's best interest to use the terminology of the standard.

Comment: Does the Standard define any term for "conversions that aren't casts"?  If it doesn't, using the common vocabulary for that meaning would seem better than either having to repeatedly use the phrase "conversions that aren't casts" or coin some other term with that meaning.

Comment: @supercat, the standard does not define a term for conversions not effected by a cast operator, and it describes the entire language without need for one.  It's a perfectly valid concept, to be sure, but it actually gets in the way in this case.  The question would read equally well if every appearance of any form of the word "coerce" were replaced with the corresponding form of "convert", with no difference in meaning because casts manifestly aren't involved anyway.

Comment: `The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion` what is lvalue conversion ?

Comment: @user2162550, "lvalue conversion" is defined in [paragraph 6.3.2.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2) of the standard.  It basically means conversion of an expression designating an object, such as a variable's name, to the value currently stored in that object.  The process drops type qualifiers (from the result, not the underlying lvalue), and the result always has non-atomic type.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, variable `a` is evaluated first in the expression, which will cause both operands to be implicitly converted to `unsigned` if they are not already, which in this case they are.  After this the left operand of the assignment operator is evaluated first, which is type `int`.  This causes implicit casting of both operands to `int` prior to performing the operation.

Implicit casting is always to the type of the operand that has higher precedence for the specific operation according to the C standard.

Implicit casting is allowable in C, but it is a better practice to always use explicit casting since it makes the sequence explicitly clear to anyone reading the code.

Comment: The question asks (only) "In what circumstances is the result of evaluating EXPR coerced? When does this coercion happen? In what cases does this coercion result in undefined behaviour?"  This does not appear to be responsive to those questions.

Comment: Moreover, this question is tagged [language-lawyer].  Such questions ask about the formal rules of the language, and can rarely be well answered without appropriate citations to the actual language standard.